# How to create a stereo WAV file from a mono file with right channel inverted with FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am not sure if the correct term should be “phase inversion,” but what I need is the right channel to be exactly the opposite to the left, this being just like the original mono.

I know this may sound silly as usually they would null each other, but case is old home computer had mono inputs that will take the right channel as ground if a stereo plug is used. This inverted channel should give a raised amplitude.

I can do it by hand or in a step by step with intermediate files but I think is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aeval](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aeval) filter for this:

```
ffmpeg -i in -af "aeval=val(0)|-val(0):c=stereo" out.wav
```